# Al recorrer por segunda mi tabla de sqlite empieza desde el segundo registro android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

Buenos días

Estoy terminando de desarrollar una app en android studio, solo que tengo un problema, yo guardo datos en una bd en sqlite, solo que al realizar un select de mi tabla me lo hace bien, pero trato de volver a recorrer mi tabla pero lo hace desde el segundo registro y no desde el primero, les dejo el código donde realizo dicho recorrido.

Les dejo el código donde primero realizo el select y ese si me recorre bien la tabla desde el primero registro pero despues trato de regresar al inicio de la tabla para recorrerla de nuevo pero solo me recorre desde el segundo registro

```
Cursor aIds = querySql("SELECT DISTINCT CLiente, FechaCobro FROM " + SqliteDB.DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_DETALLECLIENTE + " WHERE " + SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Status + " = " + " '" + true + "'", null);
        SimpleDateFormat DateFormatterd = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        int cont = aIds.getCount();
        if (aIds.getCount() > 0) {
            while (aIds.moveToNext()) {
                int _Cliente = aIds.getInt(aIds.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_CLiente));
                Date _Fecha = null;
                try {
                    _Fecha = (DateFormatterd.parse(aIds.getString(aIds.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_FechaCobro))));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Cursor aRs = querySql("SELECT * FROM " + SqliteDB.DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_DETALLECLIENTE + " WHERE " + SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Status + " = " + " '" + true + "'" + " AND CLiente=" + _Cliente +  " AND FechaCobro " + "=" + "'" + _Fecha + "'" , null);
                SimpleDateFormat DateFormatterD  = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

                if (aRs.getCount() > 0  || aRs.getCount() == _Cliente)  {
                    while (aRs.moveToNext()) {

                        Id = aRs.getInt(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ID));
                        Folio = aRs.getString(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Folio));
                        ClientClave = aRs.getInt(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_CLiente));
                        try {
                            Date Fecha = DateFormatterD.parse(aRs.getString(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Fecha)));
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        DocumentoD = aRs.getInt(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Documento));
                        DocumentoDescripcion = aRs.getString(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_DocumentoDescripcion));
                        IdCliente = aRs.getInt(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_CLiente));
                        MonedaD = aRs.getInt(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_MonedaD));
                        ImporteD = aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Importe));
                        DescuentoD = aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Descuento));
                        SubTotalD = aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_SubTotal));
                        Retencion1D = aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Retencion1));
                        Retencion2D = aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Retencion2));
                        IEPSD = aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_IEPS));
                        IVAD = aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_IVA));
                        TotalD = aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Total));
                        Saldo = aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_SaldoD));
                        Double SaldoVencido = aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_SaldovencidoD));
                        String ParcialidadD = aRs.getString(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Parcialidad));
                        Double ParcialidadTotal = aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ParcialidadTotal));
                        String PagoCondicionDescripcion = aRs.getString(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_PagoCondicionDescripcion));
                        UltimoCobroObservacion = aRs.getString(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_UltimoCobroObservacion));
                        TotalAplicado += aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_TotalApli));
                        TotalApli =  aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_TotalApli));
                        UrlD = aRs.getString(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_URL));
                        DireccionD = aRs.getString(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Direccion));

                    }
                    if (aRs.getCount() > 1)
                    {
                        if (TotalAplicado > 0 || TotalAplicado == 0 ) {
                            Factor = TotalAplicado / TotalD;

                            Importe += ImporteD * Factor;
                            Descuento += DescuentoD * Factor;
                            SubTotal += SubTotalD * Factor;
                            IVA += IVAD * Factor;
                            Retencion1 += Retencion1D * Factor;
                            Retencion2 += Retencion2D * Factor;
                            IEPS += IEPSD * Factor;
                            Total += TotalD * Factor;
                            Url = UrlD;
                            Direccion = DireccionD;
                            Cliente = IdCliente;
                            Moneda = MonedaD;
                            Observaciones = UltimoCobroObservacion;

                            O_ResultadoEncabezado = O_WS.LLenarEncabezadoCXCP("I",    //Accion I
                                    0,      //Id = 0
                                    "",
                                    new Date(),
                                    Cliente,
                                    0,
                                    Moneda,
                                    1.0,      //Tipo de Cambio por default 1
                                    0,      //Cuenta Bancaria
                                    1,          //Pago Forma
                                    Total,          //Saldo
                                    Importe,    //Importe
                                    0,          //Financiamiento
                                    Descuento,
                                    SubTotal,
                                    Retencion1,
                                    Retencion2,
                                    IEPS,
                                    IVA,
                                    0,          //ISH,
                                    Total,      //Total
                                    Total,      //totalaplicado,
                                    "A",        //status,
                                    "",         //usucariocancela,
                                    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,   //Numero1...Numero10
                                    Url, //Texto1
                                    Direccion,  //Texto2
                                    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",                      //Texto1...Texto10
                                    new Date(), new Date(), new Date(), new Date(), new Date(), new Date(),  //Fecha1...Texto6
                                    Observaciones,         //Observacion
                                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,         //Catalogo1...Catalogo6
                                    "",         //ordencompra
                                    0,          //concepto
                                    "",         //observacioncancelacion
                                    0,          //origenventacompra,
                                    0           //origeninventario
                            );

                        }
                    }else{
                        if (TotalApli > 0 || TotalApli == 0) {
                            Factor = TotalApli / TotalD;

                            Importe += ImporteD * Factor;
                            Descuento += DescuentoD * Factor;
                            SubTotal += SubTotalD * Factor;
                            IVA += IVAD * Factor;
                            Retencion1 += Retencion1D * Factor;
                            Retencion2 += Retencion2D * Factor;
                            IEPS += IEPSD * Factor;
                            Total += TotalD * Factor;
                            Url = UrlD;
                            Direccion = DireccionD;
                            Cliente = IdCliente;
                            Moneda = MonedaD;
                            Observaciones = UltimoCobroObservacion;

                            O_ResultadoEncabezado = O_WS.LLenarEncabezadoCXCP("I",    //Accion I
                                    0,      //Id = 0
                                    "",
                                    new Date(),
                                    Cliente,
                                    0,
                                    Moneda,
                                    1.0,      //Tipo de Cambio por default 1
                                    0,      //Cuenta Bancaria
                                    1,          //Pago Forma
                                    Total,          //Saldo
                                    Importe,    //Importe
                                    0,          //Financiamiento
                                    Descuento,
                                    SubTotal,
                                    Retencion1,
                                    Retencion2,
                                    IEPS,
                                    IVA,
                                    0,          //ISH,
                                    Total,      //Total
                                    Total,      //totalaplicado,
                                    "A",        //status,
                                    "",         //usucariocancela,
                                    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,   //Numero1...Numero10
                                    Url, //Texto1
                                    Direccion,  //Texto2
                                    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",                      //Texto1...Texto10
                                    new Date(), new Date(), new Date(), new Date(), new Date(), new Date(),  //Fecha1...Texto6
                                    Observaciones,         //Observacion
                                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,         //Catalogo1...Catalogo6
                                    "",         //ordencompra
                                    0,          //concepto
                                    "",         //observacioncancelacion
                                    0,          //origenventacompra,
                                    0           //origeninventario
                            );

                        }

                    }


                }

                if (O_ResultadoEncabezado.ErrorId == 0) {
                    aRs.moveToFirst();

                        while (aRs.moveToNext()) {

                            if (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_TotalApli)) > 0 || aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_TotalApli)) == 0)
                            {
                                DFactor = aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_TotalApli)) / aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Total));


                                Resultado = Integer.parseInt(O_WS.LLenarDetalleCXCP

                                        ("I", //Accion
                                                0, //id
                                                Id,  //Origen
                                                aRs.getInt(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Documento)),  //OrigenDocumento
                                                aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Importe)) * DFactor,   //Importe
                                                (Double) 0.0,  //Financiamiento
                                                aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Descuento)), //Descuento
                                                aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_SubTotal)) * DFactor,   //Subtotal
                                                aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Retencion1)) * DFactor, //Retencion1
                                                aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Retencion2)) * DFactor,  //Retencion2
                                                aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_IEPS)) * DFactor,   //IEPS
                                                aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_IVA)) * DFactor, //IVA
                                                (Double) 0.0, //ISH
                                                aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Total)) * DFactor,  //Total
                                                aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_SaldoD)),//Saldo
                                                "Android App Desconectado"      //Referencia
                                        ));
                            }

                        }
                }

                webService.STR_Resultado O_Resultado = null;

                if (Resultado == 0) {

                    ArrayList<DetalleMenu> ArrayMenu = new ArrayList<DetalleMenu>();
                    Cursor arS = querySql("SELECT * FROM " + SqliteDB.DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_Menu , null);
                    if (arS.getCount() > 0) {

                        while (arS.moveToNext()) {

                            DetalleMenu newDetalle = new DetalleMenu(
                                    (arS.getInt(arS.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_IdMenu))),
                                    (arS.getInt(arS.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_EmpresaM))),
                                    (arS.getString(arS.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_DescripcionMenu))),
                                    (arS.getString(arS.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Evento))),
                                    (arS.getInt(arS.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Modulo))),
                                    (arS.getInt(arS.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Operacion))),
                                    (arS.getInt(arS.getColumnIndex(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLIMN_NAME_Documento))));
                            ArrayMenu.add(newDetalle);
                        }

                    }

                    for (int i=0; i< ArrayMenu.size();i++)
                    {
                        Modulo = ((DetalleMenu)ArrayMenu.get(i)).getModulo();
                        Operacion =  ((DetalleMenu)ArrayMenu.get(i)).getOperacion();
                        Documento =  ((DetalleMenu)ArrayMenu.get(i)).getDocumento();
                    }


                    O_Resultado = O_WS.GrabarCxCP(Modulo,      //Modulo
                            Operacion,      //Operacion
                            Documento,      //Documento
                            0,      //OrigenId
                            0);     //OrigenDocumento

                }

                //Se inicializan Variables
                ImporteD = 0.0;
                DescuentoD = 0.0;
                SubTotalD = 0.0;
                IVAD = 0.0;
                TotalD = 0.0;
                Importe = 0.0;
                Descuento = 0.0;
                SubTotal = 0.0;
                IVA = 0.0;
                Total = 0.0;
                TotalAplicado = 0.0;
            }
```

Comment: las variables _Cliente y _Fecha tienen el mismo valor en las 2 peticiones o son distintos?

Comment: amigo actualize el codigo

Comment: si lo pudiste ver es que antes hago otra consulta

Comment: no lo he podido ver en profundidad, mañana intentaré revisarlo con más profundidad

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite cuenta con un método para este caso.
Reemplaza este if .

```
if (aIds.getCount() > 0) {

}
```

con este if;

```
 if (fila.moveToFirst()) {

 }
```

> Llamar a moveToFirst () hace dos cosas: le permite probar si la consulta devolvió un conjunto vacío (probando el valor de retorno) y mueve el cursor al primer resultado (cuando el conjunto no está vacío).